# Mongoose connection issue (node:14948)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am experiencing some issues trying to connect to a remote mongoDb in my Ubuntu  Server.

- The database name I am trying to connect is "users".
- I have a user with the dbAdmin role for the DB "users".
- I also have a user with the root role for the DB "admin".

These are the errors I am getting when node reaches the connection string line:

```
(node:14948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Authentication failed.

(node:14948) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have been trying with all these lines of code:

This is the basic structure, but it aims to the admin DB and I need it to aim to users DB:    `mongoose.connect('mongodb://usersDb_admin:secretPassword123@10x.25x.21x.23x:27017);`

This one is supposed to connect to users, but it does not work:    `mongoose.connect('mongodb://usersDb_admin:secretPassword123@10x.25x.21x.23x:27017/users');`

And this is the most complex I have tried:    `mongoose.connect('mongodb://usersDb_admin:secretPassword123@10x.25x.21x.23x:27017/users?authSource=users&w=1');`

I also tried all the previous connection strings with a dbOwner and root users. Only for the first one, it connects, but as I said, it connects to the admin DB and I need it connect to the users DB (I know this is obvious, I am just mentioning this to clarify that server/mongoose/remote access works fine).

Comment: What's the `users` string in the beginning of each connection string ? is that part of the username ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding, "users" is the name of the database I am trying to connect. Also, I have a mongo user login named "userDb_admin" which has a dbAdmin role level and it was assigned to the "users" db. Like this: db.createUser(
  {
    user: "usersDb_admin",
    pwd: "secretPassword",
    roles: [ { role: "dbAdmin", db: "users" } ]
  }
)

Comment: Note that you mentioned both `userDb_admin` and `usersDb_admin` (notice the trailing s). Can you validate which one is it and to make sure that this is not a typo that prevents you from authenticating ?

Comment: Which mongoose version is this? Can you also include the output from `npm list` from the `mongoose` tree and all it's dependents please, or at least also identify the `mongodb` package version in addition to the `mongoose` package

Comment: Also, please check where you actually created your users for authentication. In reality they are supposed to be in the `admin` database and that "should" be where the driver is attempting to authenticate by default. Showing the detail of the listed user(s) will also help here. Passwords don't show in any of the commands to retrieve details.

Comment: >Evyatar Meged: My bad at the reply... it is usersDb_admin, there is no userDb_admin, and yes, i am 100% sure it exists and using it correctly in the connection string. || 

>Neil Lunn mongoose version is "5.0.1". The user "usersDb_admin" was created for the "users" db, I am also 100% sure of this. Actually i created it this way: db.createUser( { user: "usersDb_admin", pwd: "secretPassword", roles: [ { role: "dbAdmin", db: "users" } ] } )